# Differences between DCP and ICC profiles?

Tags: color-management, icc-profile

I am trying to understand what is the best colour profile that I can generate from a ColorChecker for calibrating my camera. I always used ICC colour profile standard but now I saw also DCP colour profile standard that has the possibility to use two illuminants. From this [article](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_create_DCP_color_profiles) it seems that they are better compared to the ICC profiles because they allow using multiple illuminants I wanted to understand what are the differences between the ICC and DCP colour profiles and what are the advantages of one and the other.

Comment: Beware that generating a good profile is tricky. You need perfect illumination, (spectrum, space homogeneity, color temperature, luminosity) which is usually at the fringe of what an amateur can do.
This will be your limitation before being your choice of profile format.

Comment: DCP profiles are quite good for general camera use as @Hugues answer explains.. ICC profiles are better when you are doing reproduction photography. Particularly of CYMK type prints. where it's possible to get deltaE's quite low and hence a match. What type photography are you using profiles for?

Comment: @doug thanks for your comment, I am doing scientific photography, reprography etc. etc. hence I keep a known illuminant...

Comment: I'd stick with ICC profiles for a fixed illuminant. Also you want to use what's called "scene referred" as opposed to "output-referred" processes. I've done extensive work on scanners which are similar but not exactly the same as what you need. But it might help. You can find a discussion of the issue here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103036/how-to-fix-when-needed-scanner-large-area-spatial-crosstalk/103037#103037

Comment: The following article from the `dcamprof` manual by Mr. Torger himself can help: https://torger.se/anders/dcamprof.html#white_balance